# How to git discard branch without checkout?

Tags: git

I have made some stupid changes on a branch.

I can remove the Branch, no problem.

However I can't do it while on it.

So, I don't want those changes anymore.

If I **don't** `commit`, and I `checkout` to my "good branch", the modified references will pass.

I wish NOT that to happen.

How can I properly remove and disregard those changes for good ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
git reset --hard
```

It will revert changes to modified files.

Also if you want to remove all untracked files and directories then do

```
git clean -fd
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the following, to get to a clean state and remove your branch:

```
git reset --hard # resets git staging and your tracked files to the last commit
git clean -fd    # deletes untracked files (this is optional)
git checkout master
git branch -D <branch to remove>
```

Answer (score 1):

run

```
git checkout .
```

then switch to whatever branch you want.

Comment: That seems a very nice solution. That will checkout where ?

Comment: It will just revert changes to the latest commit.

Comment: `git checkout .` does not work, if you have already staged changes (staged changes remain untouched)

Answer (score 0):

You can `git reset --hard` to discard all current changes on the branch (if you have untracked files you can also do `git clean -f`).

After that you can `git checkout` any other branch and then delete the offending branch. (The commits themselves will remain in the repository for a while, but they will be hard to find.)